# Solution to $\Delta u = 0$ on $B, u=f$ on $\partial B$, which is of class $C^0(\bar{B})\cap C^2(B)\cap W_2^1(B)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

Let $B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit-circle and suppose that $f:\partial B\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Using the Poisson Integral, it can be shown that

$\Delta u=0$ on $B$, $u=f$ on $\partial B$

has a solution which is of class $C^0(\bar{B})\cap C^2(B)$ (cf. Gilbarg Trudinger chapter 2.5). However, the book that I am reading states that the solution of this problem is also of class $W_2^1(B)$. Could someone provide me with a reference for that statement?

Comment: Remind us what $H_2^1$ is...

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be the sobolev space $W_2^1(B)$.

Comment: RIght. Is that one derivative in $L^2$ or two derivatives in $L^1$?

Comment: One Derivative in $L^2$.

Comment: If you show that $u(re^{it})=\sum\hat f(n)r^{|n|}e^{int}$ you can calculate $||\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}||_2$ and $||\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}||_2$ by orthogonality

Comment: I think there might be an issue: If $u\in W^1_2(B)$, then by trace theorems we have that $u|_{\partial B}=f\in H^{1/2}(\partial B)$, and I'm pretty sure that continuity of $f$ is not enough to guarantee you belong to this space. This is reflected on the $n$ factor that'll pop out for $\partial_t u$ and $\partial_r u$ in @DavidC.Ullrich comment.

Comment: @Jose27 I obviously didn't work out the norm. I just had a vague idea it had to work out right because of folklore about solving the Dirichlet problem by minimizing the $L^2$ norm of the gradient. (Hmm, probably that was long ago, when functions were differentiable?)

Comment: @Jose27 Oh, right, the rest of the story is famous example showing minimum need not be attained...

Comment: @Jose27 So evidently $H^{1/2}$ is defined by $D^{1/2}f\in L^2$, or $\sum |n|\,|\hat f(n)|^2<\infty$. Yes, this is certainly a problem, since an absolutely convegent fourier series need not be in $H^{1/2}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I guess maybe in OP's textbook they say something along the lines of "if $f\in C(\partial B)\cap H^{1/2}(\partial B)$, then the Poisson kernel solution agrees with the Lax-Milgram solution" or something along this lines; this seems much more reasonable.

Comment: My question is related to the solution of Plateau's Problem, where we first minimize the Dirichlet energy in a suitable subspace of $H_2^1(B)$. The author chooses a minimizing sequence $\{X_n\}$ and then states that we can replace every $X_n$ by a surface $Z_n\in C^0(\bar{B},\mathbb{R}^3)\cap C^2(B,\mathbb{R}^3)\cap H_2^1(B)$, which is harmonic in $B$ and has smaller energy, simply by solving the problem $Z_n = 0$ on $B$, $Z_n = X_n$ on $\partial B$. It is "well-known" that this problem always has a unique solution.

Comment: Ah! Then I was correct. Since $Z_n\in C^0(\bar{B})\cap H^1_2(B)$, by trace theorems we have $Z_n\in C^0(\partial B)\cap H^{1/2}(\partial B)$, and in this case you do have that both solutions agree since the Sobolev trace agrees with the usual restriction to the boundary when the function is continuous (this is spelled out in Evans's book for example).

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe point me to the pages where Evans talks about this?